# Gmaps Polyline from json doesn't work

Tags: jquery, json, google-maps

I have a json with coordinate to create some polylines in my google maps
http://giroingiroinbicicletta.com/itinerari.json
I get this with jquery getJson and I pass the point to the google maps but doesn't work and I don't understand why

```
var map

function initialize() {
        var mapOptions = {
            zoom: 14,
            center: new google.maps.LatLng(41.90381,12.488601),
            mapTypeId: google.maps.MapTypeId.TERRAIN
        };
        map = new google.maps.Map(document.getElementById("mappa"), mapOptions); 
}

function estraiTracciati() {
    $.getJSON( "itinerari.json", function( data ) {     
        $.each(data, function() {
            var percorsoArray = [];         
            $.each(this.punti, function() {
                percorsoArray.push(new google.maps.LatLng(this));               
            })
            var polyline = new google.maps.Polyline({
                path: percorsoArray
            });
            percorsi.push(polyline);
            polyline.setMap(map);

        });
    }); 
}

google.maps.event.addDomListener(window, 'load', initialize);

$(document).ready(function() {
    estraiTracciati();
}
```

Comment: You're missing at least 3 semicolons.

Comment: Your `map` variable is local to function `initialize()` and is not visible in function `estraiTracciati()`.

Comment: A google.maps.LatLng takes two arguments, not one (even if that one is an array containing two numbers...).

Comment: Both of your polylines are identical (and have one point on the wrong side of the prime meridian) - [fiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/4nXAC/1/)

Comment: map variable is global, I made a mistake to simplify the code here

Comment: I pass to LatLng two number (check the json) and one point is on the wrong side of prime meridian because I want to see very well the track...

Comment: Missing semicolons on these lines: percorsi.push(polyline), polyline.setMap(map), estraiTracciati().  You need to learn how to use the debugger.

Comment: steve wellens you're right, this is javascript and not php and semicolons are NOT fondamental! The script, obviously, with semicolon still not working...

Comment: Please answer your own question and accept it to indicate that it is solved. Do not put the word "solved" in the title. See also: [How does accepting an answer work?](http://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/5234/how-does-accepting-an-answer-work)